# I'm trying to convert ulaw PCM to Linear PCM in Java

Tags: java, pcm, mu-law

Created code to change the PCM file encoded in java to ulaw to Linear PCM in a normal way.
Because it's a test code, it's simple to configure, and when you run it, the ulaw PCM is converted to a specific folder as Linear PCM.
So I got the file and ran it on a program called Ocean Audio, and the noise gets mixed up too much.
I converted it, but as a result, I couldn't get the song I wanted.
There seems to be no problem with Buffered InputStream, making Buffer, converting it to ByteArray
Why did this happen?

The code I tried is as follows.

```
public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException {

        String fileName = "ulaw.pcm";
        File file = new File("/home/user/" + fileName);
        FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(file);
        int read = 0;
        byte[] buff = new byte[3200];
        byte[] audioBytes;
        byte[] cvtAudioBytes;
        ByteArrayOutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        BufferedInputStream in = new BufferedInputStream(fis);
        while ((read = in.read(buff)) > 0) {
            out.write(buff, 0, read);
        }

        audioBytes = out.toByteArray();
        cvtAudioBytes = Converter.ulaw2Linear(audioBytes);
        
        Path path = Paths.get("/home/user/convert.pcm");

        Files.write(path, cvtAudioBytes);

        out.close();
        in.close();

}
```

Below is Converter Class.

```
public class Converter {
    public static byte[] ulaw2Linear(byte[] ulawBuffer) {
        int ulawSampleSize = ulawBuffer.length;
        int linearSampleSize = ulawSampleSize * 2;
        System.out.println("ulawSampleSize : " + ulawSampleSize);
        System.out.println("linearSampleSize : " + linearSampleSize);

        byte[] linearBuffer = new byte[linearSampleSize];

        for (int i = 0; i < ulawSampleSize; i++) {
            short sampleValue = ulaw2LinearSample(ulawBuffer[i]);
            //System.out.println(sampleValue);
            linearBuffer[i * 2] = (byte) (sampleValue & 0xFF);
            linearBuffer[i * 2 + 1] = (byte) ((sampleValue >> 8) & 0xFF);
        }

        for(int i=0; i<linearBuffer.length; i++) {
            System.out.println(linearBuffer[i]);
        }
        return linearBuffer;
    }

    private static short ulaw2LinearSample(byte ulawSample) {
        int ulawValue = ulawSample & 0xFF;
        ulawValue = ulawValue ^ 0xFF; 
        int sign = (ulawValue & 0x80) == 0 ? 1 : -1;
        int exponent = (ulawValue >> 4) & 0x07;
        int mantissa = ulawValue & 0x0F;
        int sampleValue = ((1 << exponent) | (mantissa << (exponent - 4)) | (1 << (exponent - 3))) - 33;
        return (short) (sampleValue * sign);
    }

}
```

The Converter class does not feel wrong because it is a universally converted code. However, the problem with the code used for the main is that
I couldn't find it. Is there anything lacking in the code?

Thank you.